# receive a custom parameter with rest api

Tags: rest-api

I have a WordPress page that show some fields that are given in the query string

for example I can call the page with :

> www.mysite.com/mypage?testparam=myvalue

and in the page I have this minimal code:

```
[insert_php]global $wp_query;if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['testparam'])){
$testparam= urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['testparam']);}
[/insert_php]

testparam is: [insert_php]var_dump ($testparam);[/insert_php]>
```

curl "http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=test-params&meta_key=test&_wp_json_nonce=4355d0c4b3&query_vars_hash=1"

So this is working well when using the standard web-way. Is there a way to pass the parameter also when requesting via the rest api ?

I tried with

> curl "http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=mypage&testparam=testvalue"

But it seems that the testparm is nowhere to be found.

Comment: You want to modify the `WP_Query`, and so the response, or to process the data inside the page template and do an action (ie send an email)?

Comment: the requirement for example is that I would be able to pass a testparam and the page should be able to display that parameter [via the rest api].

Comment: I think you misunderstanding what a RESTful API is. There is no pages but endpoints and they do not display but respond to a request and a method. Nevertheless, it is possible to pass a parameter and get a response based on that parameter. The [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) are not very good at the moment but it should give you a hint where to start. Also [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257820/wp-rest-api-core-major-changes) might help.

Comment: Plugins that let you put raw PHP code inside a posts content and execute it are incredibly dangerous, and a development dead end. It does not surprise me that you are having problems, you should not use the insert PHP shortcode plugin to do this. Build an actual shortcode instead, it will be safer, more compatible, and allow more people to help you ( you may find that someone provides the solution but you are unable to use it because you used `[insert_php]` instead of a native shortcode )